# How to collapse/expand an accordion with bootstrap progressively without close the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have the following code: http://www.bootply.com/peFUdnwOpZ

I want to open each panel when I click on the panel heading without close the others were opened, How can I do it?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not add, `data-parent="#accordion"` attribute. It will disable the accordion (one at a time) like feature.

Comment: This is what that code is written for.  it's mentioned on the official bootstrap documentation

Answer (score 0):

I've saw the docu of Bootstrap, http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse-usage
and i think it could be solved using:

```
$('#myCollapsible').collapse({
  toggle: false
})
```

Try and tell us.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes it works, you must change the id, and use your container.
In your fiddle put this js

```
$('.closeall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse.in')
    .collapse('hide');
});
$('.openall').click(function(){
  $('.panel-collapse:not(".in")')
    .collapse('show');
});
$('#container').collapse({
  toggle: false
});
```

Try and tell us.
Thanks